# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ver'

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

```
import pygame
print pygame.ver
```

throws the following exception

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ver'
```

I don't know how to fix it. I should have pygame installed but it still shows this exception.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute is [`pygame.version.ver`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.version.ver), so you need to use:

```
import pygame
print(pygame.version.ver)
```